# Putty SSH tunnelling not working for HTTPS sites

Tags: ssh, proxy, https, putty

I created a proxy by creating a SSH tunnel using PUTTY, and then filling in the values of the server in my home computer's browser proxy settings. I entered the server IP in the Socks list.

I can view all HTTP non secure sites, but when I try to go to a HTTPS site, the page comes out blank. Happens with all HTTPS sites.

Whilst connecting by putty, I even tried putting local port 443 and destination port localhost:443, and filling in the browser proxy settings for the HTTPS field, but no luck still.

Can anybody tell me how I can achieve to browser HTTPS using my proxy.

Comment: are you sure the host you're opening the SSH tunnel to is allowed to access https sites or more correctly can access a service on Port 443?

Comment: which browser are you using to access https pages?

Comment: PuTTY creates and SSL tunnel, not a proxy.  Can you clarify your setup a bit. When you say server do you mean the server you ssh'd to or the one your trying to browse to?

Comment: @Marcel G
Sorry, I asked that question without registering here, and I can't seem to comment on it now. Anyway, created user and here I am again. The server I am tunneling to is a web server that has access to https sites. I can SSH into the server, and when I do something like `telnet www.google.com 443` it says `Connection Established` @gmh1014
I tried in firefox, IE8, and Chrome. None of them working for HTTPS sites @David
I am creating a SSH Tunnel between my home computer and my VPS server, and am accessing the internet through my server using that Tunnel.

Comment: David: that's what I used to think, too, and then I was gently and courteously pointed to the `-D` flag for ssh.  Have a look at the man page!

Answer (score 1):

The server IP shouldn't be listed as your proxy if you're using ssh with -D (or equivalent). In fact, I'm surprised it works at all! When configuring ssh for SOCKS mode, you tell it a port number (in cli ssh you would do "ssh -D somenum username@server") that is the *local* port. So your SOCKS settings should point to localhost:that-port.

Answer (score 0):

A tunnel (port forwarding, really) is not a proxy per se; but, as MadHatter pointed out, ssh can act as a SOCKS proxy server if so instructed.  Not sure about PuTTY.